# Interpreting the socks5 RFC on the UDP ASSOCIATE part

Tags: sockets, networking, proxy, network-protocols, socks

> The UDP ASSOCIATE request is used to establish an association within
>      the UDP relay process to handle UDP datagrams.  **The DST.ADDR and
>      DST.PORT fields contain the address and port that the client expects
>      to use to send UDP datagrams on for the association**.  The server MAY
>      use this information to limit access to the association.  If the
>      client is not in possesion of the information at the time of the UDP
>      ASSOCIATE, the client MUST use a port number and address of all
>      zeros.

From [RFC 1928](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt), I interpret the text as that the DST.ADDR and DST.PORT is only  useful for limiting access to the association(I take *limiting access* as *preventing sending UDP through the association*)，this makes sense to me.

By following the RFC, I already implemented **client -> proxy -> remote** for UDP relay.

Now the confusion I am having is how to implement **remote -> proxy -> client**, WHAT port to listen for remote packets and WHAT port of the client to forward the packets to? The RFC does not states this clearly.